# Get the post attached to a image attachment

Tags: customization, attachments

Assuming I know the image attachment ID, how can I get the post permalink to which is attached (if any) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly this:

```
$parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $id);
$link = get_permalink($parent);
```